# BootStrap : Two Divs in a row are not getting aligned properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2">
              <h2><span class="label label-primary" id="notify">Notifications</span><h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
            <!-- Split button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Refresh">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    Mark all as read
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

And Here is the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/SimplytheVinay/0g8fm8u6/

I tried multiple combination of classes. Even setting the height of Label manually doesn't work. Somehow label is occupying more height than its size. Tried setting margins as well. No Luck.

Pretty new to web development, So correct me If I am missing anything.

Comment: This might help you get started https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/0g8fm8u6/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the H2 also for the button https://jsfiddle.net/7n0t19hr/

```
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-10">
       <h2>


        <!-- Split button -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Refresh">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                Mark all as read
            </button>
        </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
                Delete
            </button>
        </div>           
    </h2>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. This one works like a charm...Should have thought about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not closing the h2 tag.

```
<h2><span class="label label-primary" id="notify">Notifications</span><h2>
```

See. Fix that and you will be able to manipulate the height and padding or whatever.

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work...I guess label being an inline element will not have height and width properties.

Comment: The height and padding comes from the h2

Comment: Yes, You are right. I observed that all heading elements comes with default padding.